# Load independant media queries for indivisual screens - Browsers support

Tags: css, browser, responsive-design, media-queries

I am reading the amazing book of Scott Jehl "[Responsible Responsive Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsible-responsive-design)". He writes about CSS Delivering methods and requests from a server. I would like to know if all browsers support the following feature(in the example), in order to load only the necessary media query for a specific device without requesting all the other media-query files.

html example:

```
  <head>
  <link href="shared.css">
  <link href="screen480.css" media="(min-width: 480px)">
  <link href="screen980.css" media="(min-width: 980px)">
  <link href="screen1200.css" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
  </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most all major browsers will load all of the css files regardless of media query.

If you are looking to dynamically load css files based on media queries, check out Scott's [eCSSential](https://github.com/scottjehl/eCSSential).

However, be warned: often times trading network round trips for lower file size is not a good decision. Here is a great article that discusses the limitations of solutions like eCSSential: [Debunking Responsive CSS Performance Myths](https://www.igvita.com/2012/06/14/debunking-responsive-css-performance-myths/)